# Chrome delete all records of a domain?

Tags: google-chrome

So I recently changed my websites IP with cPanel, it works with my other browsers and other users however for my Chrome it loads the default "defaultwebpage.cgi" Sorry page.

It's driving me mad :( how can I delete everything that will make chrome reload the page correctly? I tried deleting cache, and pressing CTRL + F5

I deleted chrome://settings/cookies for cache

Comment: chrome://settings/cookies redirects me to just chrome://settings, did you use the "Clear Browsing Data..." button on that page?  Were the options for cookies and cached images and files checked when you did that?

Comment: How do I clear the browsing data for just one site?

Comment: Your router may also be caching DNS.

Comment: @TeddyAtlas, I don't believe you can.  You can clear browsing data by time and date, if that's any help, but I would suggest clearing all of it preferably.  Also, possibly a silly question, but you are able to browse to the site fine from other browsers on your same computer and user profile, right?